# Django how to get multiple context_object_name for multiple queryset from single view to single template

Tags: python, django

I want to run **multiple** queryset from single view.
I have done for single **get_queryset** and single **context_object_name** to pass into **index.html** template :

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'doorstep/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_hotels'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Hotel.objects.all().order_by('rating').reverse()[:3]
```

Now, i need to run this queryset 
`Hotel.objects.all().order_by('star').reverse()[:3]` 
from same **IndexView** and pass **context_object_name** from this querset to same **template_name**.

I get the value as `{% for hotel in all_hotels %}` in the template

Comment: You can write your custom templatetag for this)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) and add any additional querysets to the context.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'doorstep/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_hotels'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Hotel.objects.all().order_by('rating').reverse()[:3]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['star_hotels'] = Hotel.objects.all().order_by('star').reverse()[:3]
        # Add any other variables to the context here
        ...
        return context
```

You can now access `{{ star_hotels }}` in your template.

Comment: `kwargs` comes from the method signature `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):`